# FindControl implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net

While debugging a problem I'm having on a DetailsView finding a control in one of the templates I encountered something strange. I have implemented a recursive FindControl Extension, and it where finding a control with an id completely different from the one I where searching for. the implementation is basically calling Findcontrol on the parent control, and afterwards if nothing where found, calling the recursive function on the child controls.

I started digging into the asp.net code with reflector and found out how the implementation for a checkboxs FindControl method where (The one in System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList)

```
protected override Control FindControl(string id, int pathOffset)
{
    return this;
}
```

This now all makes sense, why my FindControl found a CheckBoxList, I can however see no reasoning behind this implementation, could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation of FindControl is overriding a recursive method.

```
protected override Control FindControl(string id, int pathOffset)
{
    return this;
}
```

Is overriding:

```
protected virtual Control FindControl(string id, int pathOffset)
{
     string str;
     this.EnsureChildControls();
if (!this.flags[0x80])
{
     Control namingContainer = this.NamingContainer;
if (namingContainer != null)
{
    return namingContainer.FindControl(id, pathOffset);
}
```

I would speculate it would be used when the recursive method is not needed IE it is known that the current control is the one you are looking for.

extra reading
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/407hh602(VS.80).aspx)

> Control.FindControl searches the current naming container for a server
>   control with the specified id and an integer, specified in the
>   pathOffset parameter, which aids in the search. You should not
>   override this version of the FindControl method.

**id**
    The identifier for the control to be found.

**pathOffset**
    The number of controls up the page control hierarchy needed to reach a naming container.

[link](http://www.sadev.co.za/node/67)